# Running 32 bits Assembly on 64 bits SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I've read

http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/463313-32-bit-clr-procedure-64-bit-sql-server.html

Does that mean it's not possible to run a 32 bits assembly on a 64 bits SQL Server? If so, what would be some solutions?

Comment: Create 64-bit assembly? Install 32-bit SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

The solution is to build it for `Any CPU`. If you are making calls out to native code via P/Invoke that requires it to be a 32-bit process, then you will have to either modify those calls to their 64-bit equivalents or find a different, managed way to achieve the result. I hope you're not doing that though, because it's a *lot* easier to break the stability guarantee usually afforded when using the CLR in SQL Server (it's called the `UNSAFE` permission set for a reason).

Comment: +1 SQLCLR assemblies should be built Any CPU, always, because databases are mobile (backup/restore, log shipping etc) and you have to consider what happen when your DB is restored on a different architecture server.